# Laravel controller action returns error 404

Tags: php, laravel-routing

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access a route linked to a controller action.

I have the route defined like this in my *routes.php* file.

```
Route::controller('error', 'ErrorsController');
```

The *ErrorsController* class looks as follows.

```
class ErrorsController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        // vacio
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('error.accessdenied');
    }

    public function getAccessDenied()
    {
        return View::make('error.accessdenied');
    }
}
```

I have a view with a link to chek if it is working properly. The link is created as follows

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('ErrorsController@getAccessDenied', 'Error') }}
```

When I click on the link the page moves to the URL *'mytestdomain.com/error/access-denied'* returning an 404 error, but when I access the URL *'mytestdomain.com/error'* it works perfectly.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Running the command `php artisan routes` these are the routes pointing to `ErrorsController`:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                                                            | Name | Action                               | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD error/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                                    |      | ErrorsController@getIndex            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD error                                                                                 |      | ErrorsController@getIndex            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD error/access-denied/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                            |      | ErrorsController@getAccessDenied     |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE error/{_missing}                                                |      | ErrorsController@missingMethod       |                |               |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Only the sencond and the fourth ones are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I found the problem.

For some reason, my apache server doesn't rewrite *mytestdomain.com/error/* * route. Probably is something related with the word error and the apache module mod_rewrite.

Anyway, defining the route as follows solves the problem.

```
Route::controller('fail', 'ErrorsController');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though specifying the route in the way you have won't work. This type of routing only works for RESTful requests. See >http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers>.

You might have to explicitly specify the route using Route::get/post.

Comment: Changing the route fixes the problem, however all the routes to my other controllers are defined the same way as this one and work too.

Comment: Besides, according to the laravel documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers) `Route::controller()` is the way of define _Implicit controllers_

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan routes`? It might shed light on the available routes. You'll probably already know this, but the `mytestdomain.com/error` is working because Laravel's router maps any "root" level URL to the index action. In this case, the `getIndex()` action.

Comment: I run the command and these are the routes pointing to `ErrorsController` :

`GET|HEAD error/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?};
GET|HEAD error , GET|HEAD error/access-denied/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?};
GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE error/{_missing}`